Why does boost geographic distance between line segment and point on line not return zero length
I have the following C++ code, where I create a line string in the geographic coordinate system. Then, I want to check the distance between the line segment and a point on the line. I expect a distance of 0.0.
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::degree degree_t;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double, boost::geometry::cs::geographic<degree_t>> point_type;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::linestring<point_type> linestring_type;

    linestring_type line;
    line.push_back(point_type(0.0,0.0));
    line.push_back(point_type(10.0,10.0));

    std::cout
        << "Line distance to (10,10): " << boost::geometry::distance(point_type(10.0,10.0), line) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

On Linux, assuming you installed libboost-dev, you can compile it and run like so:
g++ line_point.cpp -o line_point && ./line_point

The terminal output shows the following:
Line distance to (10,10): 18.9955

Is this expected behavior to have the distance reported be 19 meters off?
If yes, is there any other way to compute the distance between a line segment and a point with more accuracy?

A two-vertex line between two points not on the Equator will follow a Great Ellipse path, cutting the chord toward the appropriate pole, so yes, this is completely expected with a geodesically aware library.

Even though the test point is directly equal to one of the points defined for the segment?
